# Start Time, Run Duration & location of application by PID in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

Is there any Way to get Start Time(with date), total running time and location of a running application using its PID value under windows by using CMD or VBS? If so, how? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such (for time - path's available).

You can monitor process starts and exits and calculate it yourself.

So `Tasklist /v` gives you the command line which includes the path.

The same thing in VBS.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.Caption
Next
```

This is a VBS script that monitors process starts and exits.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
Loop
```

No such thing as StartTime

```
class Win32_Process : CIM_Process
{
  string Caption;
  string CommandLine;
  string CreationClassName;
  datetime CreationDate;
  string CSCreationClassName;
  string CSName;
  string Description;
  string ExecutablePath;
  uint16 ExecutionState;
  string Handle;
  uint32 HandleCount;
  datetime InstallDate;
  uint64 KernelModeTime;
  uint32 MaximumWorkingSetSize;
  uint32 MinimumWorkingSetSize;
  string Name;
  string OSCreationClassName;
  string OSName;
  uint64 OtherOperationCount;
  uint64 OtherTransferCount;
  uint32 PageFaults;
  uint32 PageFileUsage;
  uint32 ParentProcessId;
  uint32 PeakPageFileUsage;
  uint64 PeakVirtualSize;
  uint32 PeakWorkingSetSize;
  uint32 Priority;
  uint64 PrivatePageCount;
  uint32 ProcessId;
  uint32 QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  uint32 QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  uint64 ReadOperationCount;
  uint64 ReadTransferCount;
  uint32 SessionId;
  string Status;
  datetime TerminationDate;
  uint32 ThreadCount;
  uint64 UserModeTime;
  uint64 VirtualSize;
  string WindowsVersion;
  uint64 WorkingSetSize;
  uint64 WriteOperationCount;
  uint64 WriteTransferCount;
};
```

Comment: [image](http://s10.postimg.org/3y46zg6yh/Untitled.png) not getting path.... this is the output of `Tasklist /v`

Comment: Sorry get confused. `wmic process get /format:hform >output.htm` or `htable`. Use IE to view file.

Comment: this `wmic process get /format:htable` shows the command by which it runs not the location of application like for `nginx` it shows `nginx` and for `apache` if shows `K:\portable_server\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d K:/portable_server/apache` for `php-cgi` it shows `K:/portable_server/languages/php/php-5.6.4-Win32-VC11-x86/php-cgi.exe -b admin:9000 -c K:/portable_server/bin/php-cgi.ini`

Comment: that is not what i want. i want, for `nginx` output `K:\portable_server\nginx\nginx.exe` for `apache` output `K:\portable_server\apache\bin\httpd.exe` and for `php-cgi` output `K:\portable_server\languages\php\php-5.6.4-Win32-VC11-x86\php.exe`

Comment: Most program launches specify a full path, such as explorer (usually) and CMD. If you have a custom launcher the the API call, CreateProcess, will search for it. This is rare in normal operations. I don't klnow your programs, are any services. See `sc qc servicename` and `wmic service get pid`

Comment: these programs are not in service and from a portable drive i am launching those with cmd. whatever i have done it by using php. but can not get the start time? any idea?

Comment: As I said Start Time is not available, Windows doesn't store it (it stores how much processor time and performance data). You have to record program starts and program exits and calculate it yourself as as I showed how..

Comment: Wrong. The start time is available via the `CreationDate` property of the `Win32_Process` class. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I posted the Win32 Process class in my answer as of Vista, the base for current compatability. It is not part of the class. It also doesn't appear in MSDN.

Comment: Do you actually read what you respond to? Process start times are stored in the ***`CreationDate`*** property (the 4th property in the class description you quoted above). That property has been a member of `Win32_Process` since at least Windows 2000.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class with a VBScript to get the executable path and the start time of a process. The duration can be derived from the start time:

```
pid = 23

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Set convert = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " & pid
For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  If IsNull(p.CreationDate) Then
    'leave start time and duration empty if CreationDate can't be read
    startTime = ""
    duration  = ""
  Else
    'convert start time from a string yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff±zzz to a date
    convert.Value = p.CreationDate
    startTime = convert.GetVarDate(True)

    'calculate duration in minutes
    duration  = DateDiff("n", startTime, Now)
  End If
  WScript.Echo startTime & vbTab & duration & vbTab & p.ExecutablePath
Next
```

Note that you need the `SeDebugPrivilege` privilege (administrators have it by default) to be able to see the executable path of the processes of other users. Without that privilege `p.ExecutablePath` will be `Null` for processes not running in the context of the current user.

Comment: returning error `K:\lab>pid = 11896
'pid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

K:\lab>Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

K:\lab>Set convert = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

K:\lab>qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = "   & pid
'qry' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'pid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Each was unexpected at this time.

K:\lab>For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)`

Comment: @AlMasumNishat Why are you pasting VBScript code in a command prompt? Write it to a .vbs file and run that file with `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`.